# I need a bash script that prints the version of (Numbers Only)

Tags: command-line, bash, python, apache2, php

I need to write a script that will download apache, mariadb, python and php versions for me. Only numbers. I don't mean the usual commands like:
php --version

I want it to be displayed on the screen like this (echo command):

```
Apache 2.4.52
MariaDB: 10.6.xx
PHP: 8.1.2
Python: 3.10.4
```

How to write?

Comment: What do you mean with "download"? Are those packages installed on your system or not?

Comment: Yes, all packages are installed.

Comment: I don't know about MariaDB, but the others can be obtained using the commands `apachectl -v`, `php -v`, `python3 --version`, and some output manipulation, like `apachectl -v | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f3 | sed 's#/#: #'`

Comment: Keep in mind that you can have multiple versions of e.g. PHP installed, but at any time the command `php` will refer to one of them through the `update-alternatives` mechanism.

Comment: Command:
mariadb --version | head -1 | cut -d '' -f6 | sed 's # / #: #'
Output:
10.6.7-MariaDB,

I just like the numbers themselves, how to do? I don't want "-MariaDB,"

Comment: Append `| sed 's/-.*$//'` to the end (to remove `-MariaDB`).

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the version number yourself by piping the message into different text processing commands and get the version your way (there is no universal method).

For example:

```
python3 --version | sed 's/Python //g' # python
bash --version | head -1 | tr ' ' '\n' | grep 'version' -A1 | grep -v 'version' # bash
```

As you can see, the ways of getting the version really depends on the program's output. Here are some tips:

- Use different text processors like `grep`, `sed`, `tr` or `head`.
- Use `grep` for grepping lines
- Use `sed` for removing patterns
- To match word of line, use `tr` to convert each word into a line followed by `grep`
- Use `head` for known line to locate version
- Browse through different manpages for command options
- Patience to debug if not working

Hope my solution can achieve what you want. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The regex `/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)/g` will match any of the following:

```
2.3
2.7.15
3.7.0
```

Using a bash script to itterate the outputs of --version:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=("python3" "gedit" "vim.tiny")

for (( i = 0; i < ${#arr[@]} ; i++));
do
        comm=$(${arr[$i]} --version)
        [[ $comm =~ ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*) ]] && echo "${arr[$i]} : $BASH_REMATCH"
done
```

Output:

```
user@Computer:~$ Desktop/script.sh
python3 : 3.10.4
gedit : 41.0
vim.tiny : 8.2
```

Just Change the programs listed to the ones you want to show up.